# How to reference a view from fragment Android

Tags: java, android

Why won't this let me reference the EditText? i tried passing activity and it didn't work.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        EditText savedata = (EditText).getActivity(),findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
 EditText savedata = (EditText).getActivity(),findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
```

to

```
  EditText savedata = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
```

Assuming the edittext belongs to `fragment_home.xml`.

You can also initialize in `onActivityCreated` using `getView().findViewById(id)`

Note:

The fragment can access the Activity instance with `getActivity()` and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the activity layout:

```
View listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass reference from Activity.

Change this:

```
  EditText savedata = (EditText)rootView .findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
```